# Add 2 array values in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I a, new learner and working on home project. I stuck to to get additions of 2 array values . The array values are as follows,
Thanks for your help.. Thanks u

Array 1

```
array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
        "totalbmilk" => "168.00"
        "totala2milk" => "0.00"
        "totaljmilk" => "390.00"
    ]
]
```

Array 2

```
array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
        "totalbmilk" => "8.00"
        "totala2milk" => "5.50"
        "totaljmilk" => "2.50"
    ]
]
```

Expecting

- totalbmilk = 168 + 8 = 176
- totala2milk = 0 + 5.5 = 5.50
- totaljmilk = 390 + 2.50 = 392.50

Controller file

```php
$milksalefordairy = Dairymilksale::selectraw('
        SUM(buffalomilk) as "totalbmilk",
        SUM(a2milk) as "totala2milk",
        SUM(jerseymilk) as "totaljmilk"
    ')
    ->whereBetween('saledate', [$startdateofmonth, $enddateofmonth])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
    
$milksaleforcustomer = Customermilksale::selectraw('
        SUM(buffalomilk) as "totalbmilk", 
        SUM(a2milk) as "totala2milk",
        SUM(jerseymilk) as "totaljmilk"
    ')
    ->whereBetween('saledate', [$startdateofmonth, $enddateofmonth])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use collection methods.

```php
$milksalefordairy = Dairymilksale::selectraw('
        SUM(buffalomilk) as "totalbmilk",
        SUM(a2milk) as "totala2milk",
        SUM(jerseymilk) as "totaljmilk"
    ')
    ->whereBetween('saledate', [$startdateofmonth, $enddateofmonth])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
    
$milksaleforcustomer = Customermilksale::selectraw('
        SUM(buffalomilk) as "totalbmilk", 
        SUM(a2milk) as "totala2milk",
        SUM(jerseymilk) as "totaljmilk"
    ')
    ->whereBetween('saledate', [$startdateofmonth, $enddateofmonth])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$collection = collect([...$milksalefordairy, ...$milksaleforcustomer]);

echo $collection->sum('totalbmilk');
echo $collection->sum('totala2milk');
echo $collection->sum('totaljmilk');
```